# Reusing Existing Xquery files in IIB

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

We have existing Xquery files in Oracle Service Bus projects.If we want to resuse the xquery files in IIB projects which saves lot of development effort as there are so many xquery files already available in different projects. So we have created a POC using Saxon processor library to execute the Xquery files in Java compute node by passing Input message available in  MbMessageAssembly to XQPreparedExpression which is working fine and getting the response. Here my question is , does it have any performance impact if we follow this approach. Could you please suggest if it causes any issue or it is okay to follow this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Xquery, so my answer might not be fully accurate, but there are some recommendation by IBM on how to use external classes like JAXB inside IIB, so they are not especially against such scenario.

Of course, it will most likely have worst performances than the same code written in optimized ESQL, but I think in your case it should be relevant to perform a Proof Of Concept. Just compare the average execution time on Oracle and compare it to IIB one, and then you should be able to decide if you go with that solution or if you need to rewrite everything.

Comment: Thanks @Jérém for the response. Ok I will check the performance analysis of message flows.